# Addressing Initial High Transfer Speeds Causing Data Loss in USB File Transfers: Community Insights Needed

Tags: usb, hard-drive, filesystem

Experiencing Challenges with USB (NTFS) File Transfers: Anomalies in Initial Write Speeds Leading to Data Loss

I am currently encountering a perplexing issue during file transfers to an NTFS-formatted USB drive. Upon initiating the transfer, the progress bar displays an anticipated total USB write speed of 13-26 MB/s. However, an unusual occurrence arises as the transfer commences, with the data being sent to the USB at an unexpected speed of 170+ MB/s. This aberrant behavior results in complete data loss; upon ejecting and reinserting the USB, the files are nowhere to be found.

Furthermore, if I opt for a cut-and-paste approach to the USB, the original file is lost as well. To mitigate this, I find myself having to copy the same file multiple times. Interestingly, after two or three attempts, the data transmission to the USB stabilizes, operating at the expected normal speed, and the data is then successfully retained.

It is noteworthy that I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04, but this issue has persisted across versions 20.04 and 23.04. I am reaching out to inquire whether others within the community have encountered a similar problem and if any solutions or insights have been identified.

Comment: Isn't the initial high data rate just due to buffers along the way filling? Once the pipeline is full, the bottle neck becomes the USB drives write rate.

Comment: It wasn't like when the transfer starts, and the speed goes up and after the second it comes back to normal, it just stays at that speed until the transfer is finished,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rsync` command has an option `--bwlimit` that allows you to control the speed.

```
rsync --bwlimit=25m source_file destination/
```

There's also `pv` (pipe viewer) in combination with `cp` to control the transfer speed. For example:

```
cp source_file destination/ | pv -L 25m
```

Both will limit the transfer speed to 25mb/s.